# View or module that shows which nodes are linking to the current node?

Tags: views, nodes, navigation

Has anyone found a way to show which pages (nodes) have internal links to another page (node)? This could be a view that shows a listing for each node of a particular content type and then all the nodes that have a link to it, or perhaps a block that shows on each page (when logged in) which shows all the other nodes that link to the currently viewed node.

This would be most valuable if it not only showed links found in a "body" field or even the actual node content type fields, but rather the entire page display including blocks, etc.

For SEO reasons its nice to know what pages you have linking to each other (as well as link text would be helpful). (Its good to know other external pages linking to your website, but that's not what I'm referring to in this question - only internal links.)

Curious if anyone else ever came up with a way to do something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is far too complex to do this in regards of all the modules there are.

You could use a module like this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/intlinks

Still not all texts that are available on you page can be applied to this.

Only thing you could use is a rather weird and costly JS thing. I mean Google Analytics tracks any link on your site. So this already happens. But is this a wise idea for your internal linking? imho not.

For reliable links between Drupal Entities please rely on a node or entity reference field. By this you have links you can query and evaluate.